# Does the Bloodshed Blade hit dice damage double on a crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, critical-hit

Just clarifying for my own sake, but on page 111 in Bigby's, there's the Bloodshed Blade, which allows you to spend hit dice to add to the damage.

> Invoking the Rune. When you target a creature with an attack using this weapon, you can invoke the sword's rune, causing it to flare with crimson light and infusing your attack with bloodthirsty precision. You then spend and roll one of your unspent Hit Dice and add the number rolled to the attack roll. You can choose to invoke the rune after rolling the d20.
> **If this attack hits, you can also spend and roll any number of your unspent Hit Dice and add the total rolled to the weapon's damage.**

So, lets say I'm playing a barbarian at level 20, and I crit, and use this feature to spend 19d12 of hit dice (You need 1 to activate it). Would the dice be doubled to 38d12?
If not, it’s still a fun weapon I'll probably plan to pick up.

Comment: Deciding after the d20 roll makes this crazy

Comment: @SeriousBri Ex post facto divine smite is a staple of the paladin’s arsenal, so this isn’t a new concept.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, the damage gets doubled

This uses the same language as the Bard's **Combat Inspiration** (p. 55 *PHB*):

> A creature that has a Bardic Inspiration die from you
> can roll that die and **add the number rolled to a weapon
> damage** roll it just made.

This, like Bloodshed blade, adds the rolled number to the weapon's damage. And there is [an official ruling in the Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA250) that clarifies this counts for critical hits:

> **Does using College of Valor’s Combat Inspiration add to
> the damage of an attack count as a damage die for purposes
> of critical hits?** Yes.

And yes, this is *a lot* of damage compared to most other things a PC can do. There are [discussions on Reddit if this item is too powerful](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/15uotwg/the_new_bloodshed_blade_is_it_too_powerful/). The expected damage here could be weapon base damage (for example 14 from a critical with a greatsword) plus another 14 from maxed Con and Strength bonus from max values of 24 as a level 20 Barbarian, as you also get to add your Con bonus to damage, plus 4 if you are raging, plus an average of 247 from doubling the critical bloodshed, for a total of 279 damage. There are some monsters like ancient dragons that will survive that, but not many.

Comment: Nice work finding a parallel feature that has an official ruling.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it TOO powerful. You can only do that insane burst once. A paladin with a crit can also one-shot a boss encounter.

Comment: @Negdo Yes and you also can do lots of damage with things like meteor swam to strip boss encounters from protecting sidekicks, so I am not calling it that, I just point out that people discuss it.

Answer (score -1):

By raw no

For a dice to be doubled it needs to fit two criteria:

It needs to be a damage dice

And it needs to be part of that attack

These dice are part of the attack, but not as damage dice

Because you roll the dice Wich at that point are defined as hit dice, get the total Which is now a flat number, then add that flat number to your attack

Furthermore Because of this same wording every feature that adds bards bardic inspiration to damage also can't crit because they don't actually add damage dice only flat numbers

And yes sage advice said they crit, and sage advice by there own written rules are blatantly wrong